# Converting the hyperbola $(x - 1)^2 - y^2 = 1$ to polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert $(x - 1)^2 - y^2 = 1$ to polar form.

I expanded the binomial, simplified, and got $x^2 - y^2 - 2x = 0$.

Then I replaced $x$ with $r\cos(\theta)$ and $y$ with $r\sin(\theta)$.

After squaring, I factored out the $r^2$, and replaced $\sin^{2}(\theta) - \cos^{2}(\theta)$ with $\cos(2\theta)$.

Solving for $r$, I ended up with $r=  (2\cos(\theta))/\cos(2\theta)$.

Is there any other ways to do this without using eccentricities?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean without eccentricity?